# Does a period inside a string pattern for the glob method mean anything?

Tags: php

Our business is using an PHP program to retrieve invoice files from our server. Recently, the website we utilise this on is not retrieving the invoices.

The developer of this program is no longer at the business so I have been tasked to try and identify the issue and fix it. Having read through the code, I have come to the retrieval lines utilising the glob method:

```
foreach (glob("D:\PDFFILES\Invoices\\*" . $FI . "_INVOICE.*") as $filename) {
            $file = $filename;
            }
```

For reference, an invoice is stored in that path of course with a naming convention as such:

```
ABC123_FI12345_INVOICE
```

and sometimes can contain a few more characters after this.

I can confirm that the $FI variable is being set to what it should be as we have been using a post method and a subsequent query to get this ID.

I'm wondering if the period at the end of 'INVOICE' is what is messing this up but unsure if this has some functionality I'm unaware of. Am I right in saying that I can remove the period and the asterisk should then still recognise documents regardless. In no case do we have a period in the name so I'm unsure why the old dev did this...

Thanks

Comment: No, the dot does not have any special meaning, it just means a literal `.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax

Comment: @CBroe Okay, gonna remove it and see if the problem continues. Other than that I'm stumped.